# Why Won't Power Automate Flow Save My Email Attachments as the Email Subject Line?

Tags: office365, power-automate

[image: Flow Screenshot]

The flow template I'm using to automatically save Outlook email attachments when the word 'test' is used in the subject line (Save Office 365 email attachments to OneDrive for Business) works perfectly, until I try to add more dynamic content ('Subject') to the File Name section. When the flow is tested I'm told it ran successfully, but the saved attachments are broken files.

I've tried adding dynamic content Subject to the File Name area on both Create File actions, and selecting Subject along with Attachments as the output from previous steps. I followed the steps laid out in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fzff9vJrIx0&pp=ygUbcG93ZXIgYXV0b2FtdGUgZW1haWwgcmVuYW1l) video exactly, minus including the sender as part of the file name and linking the flow to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe the extension at the end of the file name matters and you are appending more text at the end?

Try using an expression to concatenate the strings correctly, or break your logic into 2 steps: first save the attachment and then update its metadata. You can then probably manipulate the file name without messing with the extension.